# C++: What are some general ways to make code more efficient for use with large numbers?

Tags: c++

Please when answering this question try to be as general as possible to help the wider community, rather than just specifically helping my issue (although helping my issue would be great too ;) )

I seem to be encountering this problem time and time again with the simple problems on Project Euler. Most commonly are the problems that require a computation of the prime numbers - these without fail always fail to terminate for numbers greater than about 60,000.

My most recent issue is with Problem 12:

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
> 3: 1,3
> 6: 1,2,3,6
> 10: 1,2,5,10
> 15: 1,3,5,15
> 21: 1,3,7,21
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int numberOfDivisors = 500;

//I begin by looping from 1, with 1 being the 1st triangular number, 2 being the second, and so on.
for (long long int i = 1;; i++) {
    long long int triangularNumber = (pow(i, 2) + i)/2
    //Once I have the i-th triangular, I loop from 1 to itself, and add 1 to count each time I encounter a divisor, giving the total number of divisors for each triangular.
    int count = 0;
    for (long long int j = 1; j <= triangularNumber; j++) {
        if (triangularNumber%j == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    //If the number of divisors is 500, print out the triangular and break the code. 
    if (count == numberOfDivisors) {
        cout << triangularNumber << endl;
        break;
    }
}

}
```

This code gives the correct answers for smaller numbers, and then either fails to terminate or takes an age to do so!

So firstly, what can I do with this specific problem to make my code more efficient?

Secondly, what are some general tips both for myself and other new C++ users for making code more efficient? (I.e. applying what we learn here in the future.)

Thanks!

Comment: Better algorithms? ... Making specific code parts faster can be done, but it won't get anywhere near to the performance increase of a good algo (compared to your nested loops)

Comment: And sometimes, you just can't use the normal int/long variables, because your values are too large.

Comment: @deviantfan Does learning how to write a 'good algo' simply come with experience, or are there specific learning resources that I should invest some time in? The issue is that if I just continue to do these problems I don't really see my algorithms getting much better than the use of nested loops, or is that simply naive?

Comment: You need to study the mathematics behind the problem.

Comment: It is easy to prove that number with at least 9 distinct prime divisors have at least 512 divisors. I am not sure how you would take into account divisors formed from repeated prime divisors, but it could be a start. Also nth triangle number is `(n*n + n)/2`

Comment: In addition to understanding the mathematics of the problem, you also need to understand limitations of languages and language features you use.   For example:  If your approach for computing primes fails for values above about 60000, odds are you are using an `unsigned` type.   The C++ standard allows an `unsigned` type to support a range of values as small as `0U` to `65535U`.

Comment: I actually use python for project euler and algorithm classes. Its arbitrarily large integers and hash based dict are great for these, and speed is not generally an issue. These problems are designed to completely overwhelm bad algorithms, so it doesn't matter how fast they are, whereas good algorithms can easily finish even on a slower implementation. To do them in c++, there's no trick -- you just need a way to store integers big enough to work on the problem, which generally requires some non-standard big int class.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that your end condition is bad.  You are supposed to stop when count > 500, but you look for an exact match of count == 500, therefore you are likely to blow past the correct answer without detecting it, and keep going ... maybe forever.

If you fix that, you can post it to code review. They might say something like this:

Break it down into separate functions for finding the next triangle number, and counting the factors of some number.

When you find the next triangle number, you execute pow. I perform a single addition.

For counting the number of factors in a number, a google search might help. (e.g. http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/NumberOfFactors.shtml )  You can build a list of prime numbers as you go, and use that to quickly find a prime factorization, from which you can compute the number of factors without actually counting them. When the numbers get big, that loop gets big.

Answer (score 0):

**Tldr: 76576500.**

About your Euler problem, some math:

Preliminary 1:
Let's call the n-th triangle number `T(n)`.
`T(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (n^2 + n)/2` (sometimes attributed to Gauss, sometimes someone else). It's not hard to figure it out:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 =  
(1+10) + (2+9) + (3+8) + (4+7) + (5+6) =  
11 + 11 + 11 + 11 + 11 =  
55 =  
110 / 2 =  
(10*10 + 10)/2
```

Because of its definition, it's trivial that `T(n) + n + 1 = T(n+1)`, and that with `a<b`, `T(a)<T(b)` is true too.

Preliminary 2:
Let's call the divisor count D. `D(1)=1`, `D(4)=3` (because 1 2 4).
For a `n` with `c` non-repeating prime factors (not just any divisors, but prime factors, eg. `n = 42 = 2 * 3 * 7` has `c = 3`), `D(n)` is `c^2`: For each factor, there are two possibilites (use it or not). The 9 possibile divisors for the examples are: 1, 2, 3, 7, 6 (2*3), 14 (2*7), 21 (3*7), 42 (2*3*7).
More generally with repeating, the solution for `D(n)` is multiplying (Power+1) together. Example `126 = 2^1 * 3^2 * 7^1`: Because it has two 3, the question is no "use 3 or not", but "use it 1 time, 2 times or not" (if one time, the "first" or "second" 3 doesn't change the result). With the powers 1 2 1, `D(126)` is `2*3*2=12`.

Preliminary 3:
A number `n` and `n+1` can't have any common prime factor `x` other than 1 (technically, 1 isn't a prime, but whatever). Because if both `n/x` and `(n+1)/x` are natural numbers, `(n+1)/x - n/x` has to be too, but that is `1/x`.

Back to Gauss: If we know the prime factors for a certain `n` and `n+1` (needed to calculate `D(n)` and `D(n+1)`), calculating `D(T(n))` is easy. `T(N) = (n^2 + n) / 2 = n * (n+1) / 2`. As `n` and `n+1` don't have common prime factors, just throwing together all factors and removing one 2 because of the "/2" is enough. Example: `n` is 7, factors `7 = 7^1`, and `n+1 = 8 = 2^3`. Together it's `2^3 * 7^1`, removing one 2 is `2^2 * 7^1`. Powers are `2 1`, `D(T(7)) = 3*2 = 6`. To check, `T(7) = 28 = 2^2 * 7^1`, the 6 possible divisors are 1 2 4 7 14 28.

What the program could do now: Loop through all n from 1 to something, always factorize n and n+1, use this to get the divisor count of the n-th triangle number, and check if it is >500.

There's just the tiny problem that there are no efficient algorithms for prime factorization. But for somewhat small numbers, todays computers are still fast enough, and keeping all found factorizations from 1 to n helps too for finding the next one (for n+1). Potential problem 2 are too large numbers for longlong, but again, this is no problem here (as can be found out with trying).

With the described process and the program below, I got

> the 12375th triangle number is 76576500 and has 576 divisors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

const int limit = 500;

vector<uint64_t> knownPrimes; //2 3 5 7...

//eg. [14] is 1 0 0 1 ... because 14 = 2^1 * 3^0 * 5^0 * 7^1
vector<vector<uint32_t>> knownFactorizations;

void init()
{
    knownPrimes.push_back(2);
    knownFactorizations.push_back(vector<uint32_t>(1, 0)); //factors for 0 (dummy)
    knownFactorizations.push_back(vector<uint32_t>(1, 0)); //factors for 1 (dummy)
    knownFactorizations.push_back(vector<uint32_t>(1, 1)); //factors for 2
}

void addAnotherFactorization()
{
    uint64_t number = knownFactorizations.size();
    size_t len = knownPrimes.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(!(number % knownPrimes[i]))
        {
            //dividing with a prime gets a already factorized number
            knownFactorizations.push_back(knownFactorizations[number / knownPrimes[i]]);
            knownFactorizations[number][i]++;
            return;
        }
    }

    //if this failed, number is a newly found prime
    //because a) it has no known prime factors, so it must have others
    //and b) if it is not a prime itself, then it's factors should've been
    //found already (because they are smaller than the number itself)

    knownPrimes.push_back(number);

    len = knownFactorizations.size();
    for(size_t s = 0; s < len; s++)
    {
        knownFactorizations[s].push_back(0);
    }

    knownFactorizations.push_back(knownFactorizations[0]);
    knownFactorizations[number][knownPrimes.size() - 1]++;
}

uint64_t calculateDivisorCountOfN(uint64_t number)
{
    //factors for number must be known
    uint64_t res = 1;
    size_t len = knownFactorizations[number].size();
    for(size_t s = 0; s < len; s++)
    {
        if(knownFactorizations[number][s])
        {
            res *= (knownFactorizations[number][s] + 1);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

uint64_t calculateDivisorCountOfTN(uint64_t number)
{
    //factors for number and number+1 must be known
    uint64_t res = 1;
    size_t len = knownFactorizations[number].size();
    vector<uint32_t> tmp(len, 0);
    size_t s;
    for(s = 0; s < len; s++)
    {
        tmp[s] = knownFactorizations[number][s]
            + knownFactorizations[number+1][s];
    }
    //remove /2
    tmp[0]--;
    for(s = 0; s < len; s++)
    {
        if(tmp[s])
        {
            res *= (tmp[s] + 1);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    init();
    uint64_t number = knownFactorizations.size() - 2;
    uint64_t DTn = 0;

    while(DTn <= limit)
    {
        number++;
        addAnotherFactorization();
        DTn = calculateDivisorCountOfTN(number);
    }

    uint64_t tn;
    if(number % 2) tn = ((number+1)/2)*number;
    else tn = (number/2)*(number+1);
    cout << "the " << number << "th triangle number is "
        << tn << " and has " << DTn << " divisors" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

About your general question about speed:

1) Algorithms.

How to know them? For (relatively) simple problems, either reading a book/Wikipedia/etc. or figuring it out if you can. For harder stuff, learning more basic things and gaining experience is necessary before it's even possible to understand them, eg. studying CS and/or maths ... number theory helps a lot for your Euler problem. (It will help less to understand how a MP3 file is compressed ... there are many areas, it's not possible to know everything.).

2a) Automated compiler optimizations of frequently used code parts / patterns

2b) Manual timing what program parts are the slowest, and (when not replacing it with another algorithm) changing it in a way that eg. requires less data send to slow devices (HDD, hetwork...), less RAM memory access, less CPU cycles, works better together with OS scheduler and memory management strategies, uses the CPU pipeline/caches better etc.etc. ... this is both education and experience (and a big topic).

And because long variables have a limited size, sometimes it is necessary to use custom types that use eg. a byte array to store a single digit in each byte. That way, it's possible to use the whole RAM for a single number if you want to, but the downside is you/someone has to reimplement stuff like addition and so on for this kind of number storage. (Of course, libs for that exist already, without writing everything from scratch).

Btw., `pow` is a floating point function and may get you inaccurate results. It's not appropriate to use it in this case.